# How to prevent restarting of core plugin when a service plugin is updated..?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi

How to prevent restarting of core plugin when a service plugin is updated by running Update command with URI of new plugin in OSGi console?

Comment: Are you talking about Eclipse-plugins?

Comment: Sorry for unclear question..
The scenario is I have THREE OSGi bundles
**A-is launcher (CORE bundle)
B-is a service bundle
C-is a service bundle**

When all of them are **ACTIVE** , **I want to update Service B bundle without affecting my other plugins(bundles).**

I am asking this since I need to explicitly run 
**refresh <bundle-id-of-updated-bundle> command in CLI of OSGi.**

Since I am a newbie to OSGi(Equinox), I apologize if I am missing something obvious.
Thanks in Advance.
Regards,
Parimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only change the service implementation that you need by moving the service interface into a separate bundle, both - your "core" bundle as well as the service implementation bundle - will depend on the service interface (aka. "service api") bundle. However, your core bundle will no longer depend on the service implementation bundle. You can then start/stop/restart/update the service implementation bundle without interrupting the core bundle.

Comment: @PatelParimal: If that answer solves your problem, then you should accept it.